# Delete Room Member from chat room using openfire server

Tags: java, api, rest, xmpp, openfire

I am new to openfire xmpp protocol. I have been create chatroom successfully, now i want to do delete room member from room using REST API.
I has been refer the [link](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#delete-a-user-from-a-chat-room) mentioned here.
 for delete room member for chat room.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "leaveGroup", headers = {"ACCEPT=*/*"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain")
    public @ResponseBody
    String leaveGroup(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        getRestClient();
        try {
            List<String> memberList = restApiClient.getChatRoom("chatrooms").getMembers();
            for (String string : memberList) {
                System.out.println("user::" + string);
            }
            // http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms/chatrooms/members/rajesh3@peacock-hp

            getJsonFromWEBService("http://192.168.168.24:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms/chatrooms/members/rajesh3@peacock-hp");

            //List<String> memberList1 = restApiClient.getChatRoom("chatrooms").getMembers().remove("rajesh3@peacock-hp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "leaveGroup";
    }

    public void getJsonFromWEBService(String serviceURL) {
        URL url;
        try {
            System.out.println("serviceURL::" + serviceURL);
            url = new URL(serviceURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            System.out.println("conn::" + conn);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU=");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            conn.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            System.out.println("status::"+conn.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("msg::"+conn.getResponseMessage());
            System.out.println("req::"+conn.getRequestProperties());
            //conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
            conn.disconnect();
            System.out.println("end..........................................");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I got error

```
Info: Response status::401
Info:   Response msg::Unauthorized
```

here openfire console' log file

```
2016.07.23 12:14:41 org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager - error in opening zip file 
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file 
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) 
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219) 
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149) 
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) 
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager$PluginMonitor.unzipPlugin(PluginManager.java:1069) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager$PluginMonitor.run(PluginManager.java:961)
```

How to get resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an older version of openfire you can not use JID in the path of your request. (rajesh3@peacock-hp).
Try just rajesh3 instead.

Comment: I tried for rajesh3 but it was not work for me. and i used openfire version is 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

In documentation it's possible to read this examples:

```
 /chatrooms/{roomName}/{roles}/{name}
```

So your attempt it's to remove from "members" user "rajesh3@peacock-hp" on chatroom named "**chatrooms**", i don't think this can work!

**You need the chatroom name** (es: `mychatroom@conference.peacock-hp`) and, before all, check if `rajesh3@peacock-hp` it's already a *member* of this chatroom (check on Openfire admin to avoid errors:

```
Admin console -> Uppertab: Group Chat -> select the service -> select your chatroom -> on left "Permissions" ->  rajesh3@peacock-hp must figure out as "member")
```

If you want to remove rajesh3@peacock-hp in a global mode, set `global` as `roomName`

---

EDIT: By the way, error reported it's about a plugin not loaded correctly, it has no effects on delete room member operation.